# WebRTC MediaStream frame callback

Tags: javascript, webrtc, video-streaming

In my Javascript app I receive a video track over WebRTC through a datachannel. Signaling and connection to the server (seemingly) work as expected.

As I need to do some processing with the received video frames, I was looking for a callback or event that is fired when a new frame has arrived. Reading through the WebRTC spec I don't see that this is available.

With Java it is possible to instantiate a new sink and set it to a track. Isn't this available for Javascript?

Any suggestions on how I could create a synchronized call to the stream?

Thanks,
Michael